# Programmatically change tab using tabify jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, jquery-tabs

I am using tabify http://unwrongest.com/projects/tabify to show tabs.

I am struggling to figure out how to change the tab programmatically.

Here is one working example: http://jsfiddle.net/S78Bt/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu').tabify();
});
```

Although I know that using JQuery UI tabs I can acheive this behavior, but due to some unavoidable circumstances I need to use tabify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project you are using seems [dead](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-tabify), it hasn't received updates lately, it does not have documentation.

I've taken a look at the source code, there is no API to access tabs for you directly.

The only solution is to hack indirectly by seeing how the library expects the tabs to change:

```
function changeTab(name) {
    location.hash = name + '-tab';
}
```

This works on [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/S78Bt/2/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the best way, but it works at least.
If we look at source code of tabify plugin you will see:

```
function getHref(el){
    hash = $(el).find('a').attr('href');
    hash = hash.substring(0,hash.length-4);
    return hash;
}

function setActive(el){         
    $(el).addClass('active');
    $(getHref(el)).show();
    $(el).siblings('li').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(getHref(this)).hide();
    });
}
```

You may use similar approach: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S78Bt/3/)

Comment: This isn't a good way, because it's almost reimplementing the entire library yourself. In addition, as soon as any changes are made to the library, this is likely to break. Copy-paste is always bad.

Comment: @Denis, I do agree copy/paste is really bad almost always, but how can you explicitly use library/plugin without depending on it?

Comment: You use that plugin API. APIs are not supposed to change. Implementation is supposed to change. You rely on implementation - on class name "active" on using "siblings" and other details that can change. Although there's no official API in this library, we can still try to discern the semantic trigger, I've described it in my answer.

Comment: @Denis, agree. But conceptually both single line `location.hash = 'usage-tab'` and two functions from my solution depends on the plugin internal implementation. What if you use that line in a lot of places, and suddenly next plugin version removes *-tab* suffix or changes it? So anyway either single-line-hack or two functions should be encapsulated in exactly one place. Such that when next tabify version is released, we need to modify only that one place. I do not argue that your solution is shorter, easier to modify and as a result - better. But I do agree there is a way to not depend at all.

Comment: ... to not depend at all unless there is API. tabify has no API so there is no way to no depend at all from internal implementation. More importantly is that we encapsulate our hack whether it's single line or few functions.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it's absolutely mandatory to create a helper function, I did not mean to use the `location.hash` everywhere directly. That aside, I find that it's less likely that updates to tabify would change its usage of `location.hash`, and it's more likely that it would slightly change its internal HTML structure. But all in all, we completely agree with you.